# Check HTML element type for result of React Testing Library's getByText?

Tags: react-testing-library

I can find an element by its text and check that it's a link with:

```
const Link = Parent.getByText('This is a link', { exact: false });
expect(Link).toHaveAttribute('href', 'www.somewhere.com');
```

How can I check this other element (which I find by text) is not a link?

```
const NotALink = Parent.getByText('Not a link', { exact: false });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing library docs have a [priority](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#priority), and the first query they recommend is the `queryByRole`, where [you can query by a specific role](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole), and also by a name, which is your case.

You can do:

```js
expect(screen.getByRole('link', { name: /this is a link/i })).toBeInTheDocument();

expect(screen.queryByRole('link', { name: /not a link/i })).toBe(null);
```

Note that you need to do queryBy if the element does not exist, as the getBy query will throw an error and will make your test fail.