# How to check with react testing library that the rendered element is of type 'div'?

Tags: react-testing-library

I have checked this answer: [Check HTML element type for result of React Testing Library's getByText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66229480/check-html-element-type-for-result-of-react-testing-librarys-getbytext) but unfortunately, `div` does not have a default role assigned (as can be checked here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance)

So my below test fails:

```
  it('should render as div when the "as" attribute is passed with a value of "div"', () => {
    render(<Button label={testText} as='div' data-testid='test-button'/>)

    expect(screen.getByTestId('test-button')).toBe('div')
  })
```

I am not able to find a query which would be good for testing this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why not using `data-testid` attribute and query the element by `screen.getByTestId(xxx)`?

Comment: thanks @slideshowp2, I updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check the element type you could access the `nodeName` from any HTMLElement returned by the `screen.getByTestId`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName

You could try something like that:

```
  it('should render as div when the "as" attribute is passed with a value of "div"', () => {
    render(<Button label={testText} as='div' data-testid='test-button'/>)
    
    expect(screen.getByTestId('test-button').nodeName.toLowerCase()).toBe('div')
  })
```

Comment: Great! in typescript I had to change just a little but is the same:

 expect(screen.getByTestId('test-button').nodeName.toLowerCase()).toBe('div');